# react-cosmos vs atellier vs React Storybook for building UI components

Tags: reactjs, web-component

My team and I are using React in our project and we were thinking about using one of these tools [react-cosmos](https://react-cosmos.github.io/), [Atellier](http://scup.github.io/atellier/) or [React Storybook](https://getstorybook.io/) for building UI components.

**My questions**

What are the main differences between those 3 tools?

What are cons and pros for using each one?

**Update**

Since I started to investigate this I found https://npmcompare.com/compare/kadira-storybook,react-cosmos-webpack

and

https://github.com/react-cosmos/react-cosmos/issues/233

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Storybooks come with a lot of helpful features. Such as snapshot test.